# Fullcalendar is showing the wrong number of weeks for September with weekMode = 'variable' or 'liquid'

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar 1.6.4 in conjunction with a Drupal 7 site; all is well except that I'm getting the wrong number of weeks for some months with weekMode set to "variable" or "liquid".  For September 2013, I get four rows of weeks, which means that I lose the last two days of the month.  Most other months appear correctly, although December 2012 is shown with 5 weeks (losing the 30th and 31st), and January, February, and October 2013 are all shown with 6 weeks (one more than is needed).

I've been doing some quick hacking around with the `render()` code where the starting and ending dates seem to be worked out, but haven't come up with anything clearly better.  So: are other people seeing this / is it a known issue / have I screwed up something with my installation?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm running into the same thing with March 2014. The last week is not displayed, which would normally include the Monday as the 31st.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a bug here: in fullcalendar.js's `MonthView.render()`, it looks like the `AddDays` computation of visEnd (l. 1984) is getting messed up by `firstDay` getting string-concatenated into the value instead of added. `visStart` may be getting similarly affected, since it does pretty much the same thing.  In any case, I stuck the line `firstDay = parseInt(firstDay, 0)` after the `var FirstDay...` statement, and things are working properly for me.  This may not be the preferred way of handling the matter, but I think something like this is going on.  Opinions from other eyes?

Comment: Fixed for me as well. `vizStart` is not vulnerable because it doesn't use concatenation, while `vizEnd` does with the `+` operator. Since `firstDay` is a string, it doesn't convert that string to an integer and "add" them as we want it to.

Comment: Actually looks like this is a bug in Drupal's full calendar implementation. It's storing the firstDay option as a string when it [should be an integer](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/firstDay/)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Full Calendar bug, but instead a bug in the Drupal implementation of Full Calendar. Drupal allows users to override the "start of the week" option (values of 0 to 6). Drupal is incorrectly storing this value as a string instead of a number.

[See Drupal issue I opened](https://drupal.org/node/2229861).